# Is there any explosion hazard with an enclosed graphite crucible melting silver?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, safety

the crucible volume is about 2 ounces.   The final design of the crucible will be enclosed tightly except for a small .5mm diameter hole at the bottom and a 1mm diameter hole at the top through which silver solder will feed.

I was wondering.  In my experiments should I worry about the thing exploding?

Comment: you should worry about your graphite slowly oxidizing. Slowly.

Comment: So producing CO2?

Comment: Well, if both holes get clogged somehow, and then you seal it shut and start heating... though the volume is too small for a decent explosion, this does not sound good.

Comment: What type of shield do you recommend?  Will some acryllic panels work?  The size of the crucible internally is now 6mm ID x 30mm Depth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Silver will absorb oxygen readily from air while molten and spatter as it cools.](http://www.lbma.org.uk/assets/blog/alchemist_articles/Alch47Stokes.pdf) This is hardly an explosion, but some care should be taken to avoid being spattered with hot particles ejected from the crucible or plugging the holes.